# How to sort shop page by a field in another table

Tags: php

I have a wordpress/woocommerce setup for a site that sells mobile phone accessories. On the shop page, I'm using a plugin called YMM where users can use dropdowns to select their phone make/model. Once they do that, it displays compatible products.

I'd like to sort those results by a field in the YMM database table, but I can't seem to get it to work. Rather, it's sorting by the date created field in the wp_posts table.

The YMM database table has these columns:

- ID: The unique sorting ID
- product_id: corresponds to the woocommerce product ID in the posts table
- make: the phone's maker (ie.. Samsung,Google,etc..)
- model: the phone's model (ie.. Galaxy,Pixel,etc...)
- engine: the phone's version (ie... S22,7,etc...)
- note: indicates whether a product is the best fit for that phone. If it's the best fit, that field just has "Best Fit". If not, it's blank.

When someone uses the YMM selector to find compatible products on the shop page, I'd like to display the results that have a note of "Best Fit" before the others. I'm not very good with PHP, and the plugin's developer was kind enough to give me some code to add:

```
if (isset($_GET['ymm_search'])){
         add_filter('posts_join', array($this, 'join_ymm_table'));
          add_filter('posts_orderby', array($this, 'order_products_by_ymm')); 

    }    
public function join_ymm_table ($join) {
      global $wpdb;
      $posts_stats_table = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
      $posts_stats_view_join = "JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}ymm AS ymm ON $wpdb->posts.ID = ymm.product_id";
      $join .= $posts_stats_view_join;  
      return $join;
      }

    public function order_products_by_ymm ($orderby) {
      global $wpdb;
      $posts_stats_table = $wpdb->prefix . "posts";
      $orderby = "if(ymm.note = 'Best Fit',0,1)," . $orderby;
      return $orderby;
      }
```

However, this isn't working and I've been messing around with trying to fix it for days. It still sorts results by date created. Can anyone tell me what I can do to make this work correctly?